# Hide my jpg files

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I develop a game that will have to load jpg images that now i just put in the same folder where swf file is, in order to load them when it is needed. Is there a way to somehow embed all this stuf in the swf so that i will have to deliver only the swf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use the [embed](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/embed_metadata_02.html) metatag :

```
[Embed(source="myImg.jpg")]
private var myImg : Class;
```

//...

```
var pic:DisplayObject = new myImg() as DisplayObject;
addChild(pic);
```

Comment: flash cs4 prompts to add flex sdk but i have not installed this library. Do everyone that needs to run the swf have to install the flex sdk?

Comment: No it s only used when compiling the swf. The part of flex sdk used is installed with cs4. The path used is : $(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/libs/flex_sdk_3/

Comment: The warning means that you are using the embed tag [Embed] and flash compiler doent's support this, so it tells you that you need to compile the project with flex sdk. It's a just a different way to compile the swf, take a look into this page it you want to take this approach: 

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/embed_metadata.html

If you don't use the flex compiler it wouldn't prompt users for the library, it would simply not compile properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Flash IDE (I presume you use cs4 after your comment) you just need to import your images to library and export to actionscript.

```
// myBitmapData is the class name for the BitmapData symbol in the library
// Create a new myBitmapData object instance called myBitmapDataObject
var myBitmapDataObject:myBitmapData = new myBitmapData(100, 100);

// Create a bitmap object instance called myImage to contain the bitmap data
var myImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapDataObject);

// Add myImage to the display list of the current Timeline
addChild(myImage);
```

Take a look into this document for more details:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/loading_images_library_as3/#c

This way the image can be used with actionscript as Bitmapdata.